# constrained Quadratic forms

Tags: quadratic-forms

suppose I have the following quadratic form
$$
{\bf{x^{\top}Ax}} = constant
$$
 where A is positive definite and I know that 
$$
{{\bf{x}}^ \top }{\bf{1}} = 1
$$

Is there an analytical solution to this problem. I can reduce it to the following form
$$
{\bf{y}} = {A^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\bf{x}}{\rm{\space\space\space\space\space st:\space }}{{\bf{y}}^ \top }{\bf{y}} = 1
$$
 and further reduce it to
$$
{{\bf{1}}^ \top }{{\bf{A}}^{ - \frac{1}{2}}}{\bf{y}} = 1
$$

but I don't know how to proceed from here. Any suggestions besides using numerical methods ?

Comment: "Suppose I have the following form... and I know that... Is there a solution to this problem?" What is "the problem"? To find all such $A$?

Comment: No. To find an x. I have level sets from the quadratic form and the constraint makes it such that the plane defined by the constraint is tangential to the level sets